# What does Windows Setup (the CD) run off of?

Tags: windows-10, windows-installation

I was installing windows 10 the other day, and noticed that the installer contains most of the administrative tools (registry editor, cmd.exe) and is perfectly capable of running .exe files. It appears that it is running a limited version of Windows XP.

How does the Windows 10 Installer work, and would it be possible to run any executable on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Windows installer runs, rather unsurprisingly, on Windows.

The exact environment is known as Windows PE. Microsoft has some basic documentation [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/winpe-intro) on it, including info on how to create custom environments based on it.

It intentionally lacks a number of widely used Windows features because they're generally not needed in such an environment (stuff like running as a terminal server, installing MSI packages (in the PE environment itself), remote desktop functionality, and numerous other things).

Comment: Great! I knew it was some form of windows by the fact that the setup itself is a .exe. They should really add some security because if you have a bootable USB drive with the installer on it you can create an admin account on any computer you want. The command prompt that comes with the installer has unlimited Administrator access.

Comment: There's no way to prevent that. The environment is designed to be usable for things like data recovery and new installs, so it can't rely on _anything_ on the system it's booted on. It's also not unique in that respect, you can usually get equivalent access from almost any bootable environment you care to name. If you're that worried about security, you should disable USB boot in the system firmware and then password-protect the firmware configuration.

Comment: Yes, after reading the entire article it does mention possible use cases. Thanks!

Comment: You can prevent unauthorized accounts from being created by using BitLocker and Secure Boot.  Any configuration change to the boot order would require the recovery key for the drive.  Firmware password also prevents boot order changes.

Comment: Yes, however jamming F8 on any version of windows will automatically boot from usb with default config